# Adding percentiles and summary statistics to ggplot boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot, summary, percentile

Looking for some help with adding summary statistics like 0.25 and 0.75 percentile lines to ggplot boxplot.

My current code is as follows:

```
ggplot(aes(y = HT, x = LOCATION, fill = LOCATION, na.rm = TRUE), data = HD1) + geom_boxplot(notch = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = c("NVRN", "PCN"), values=c("sky blue", "red"))+
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,80)) +
  geom_smooth(method="lm") + theme_bw() + theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

My data is quite simple with one response and one predictor  - the predictor has two categorical groups (2 locations) and I need to add the summary statistics directly onto the `ggplot`.

I have tried using different functions like `add_summary` and `stat_summary` to add percentile lines (in red) and means for both groups onto my `ggplot`. I cannot seem to figure out exactly how to do this with my code, any help would be much appreciated.

I hope this is enough information.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand the regression line in a box-and-whiskers plot. Is it really necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution.
In the case below a mean line is added. Other statistics can be added with similar code, just change the function `fun=mean` to the relevant function.

```r
library(ggplot2)

HD1 <- iris[51:150, 4:5]
names(HD1) <- c("HT","LOCATION")
brks <- unique(HD1[[2]])

ggplot(data = HD1, aes(x = LOCATION, y = HT, fill = LOCATION)) + 
  geom_boxplot(notch = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_manual(breaks = brks, values = c("sky blue", "red")) +
  stat_summary(aes(ymax = ..y.., ymin = ..y..),
               geom = "errorbar", fun = mean,
               width = 0.70,
               size = 1.5, linetype = "dotted") +
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>